# Magento - Change main product image on thumbnail hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, thumbnails

In Magento, on a product page, how can I have the main product image change when hovering over a thumbnail instead of having to click the thumbnail for the main image to change?  I've searched everywhere and can't find any solution that works.  I'm using magagento 1.9.2.0.

I think I would need to add some code to whatever JS file that has a click handler attached to each thumbnail, but I dont know how to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using rwd theme then just go to the file skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js and search for

```
$j('.product-image-thumbs .thumb-link').click(function(e) {
```

You will find it in line number 1246(can be different) then replace this by

```
$j('.product-image-thumbs .thumb-link').hover(function(e) {
```

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Works perfectly!